# Where do I find a site that provides indicator applets like weather indicator?

Tags: indicator, gnome-panel, panel-applets

I am looking for a site that I can find applets for gnome-panel just like gnome-shell has this extension.gnome.org

Any idea?

Comment: For 12.10, try [this](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/tag/indicatorapplets). For 11.10, try [this](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/01/the-omg-guide-to-must-have-indicator-applets).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-ppa-repositories/18177-ubuntu-1204-my-weather-indicator-with-geolocation-support

**Ubuntu 12.04 My Weather Indicator with geolocation support**

Panel-based weather applet My Weather Indicator has added geolocation support, providing input free location detection based on your IP.

**Install in Ubuntu 12.04 via ppa**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install my-weather-indicator
```